# Downloading dynamic web pages in python

Tags: python, python-requests

I use the python requests (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library in order to download and parse particular web pages. This works fine as long as the page is not dynamic. Things look different if the page under consideration uses javascript.

In particular, I am talking about a web page that automatically loads more content once you scrolled to the bottom of the page so that you can continue scrolling. This new content is not included in the page's source text, thus, I can't download it.

I thought about simulating a browser in python (selenium) - is this the right way to go?

Comment: Content is probably loaded through AJAX requests, so ... do these requests ?

Comment: Basically, yes. You need to run something that will execute javascript.

Comment: I'm wondering why you'd use something like requests when things like scrapy (http://scrapy.org/) exist. For dynamic pages, you can also use splash with scrapy (http://blog.scrapinghub.com/2015/03/02/handling-javascript-in-scrapy-with-splash/). Or you could go the selenium route- you'll get at the same destination.

Comment: @criswell You trade complexity (manually crafted requests) for a few orders of magnitude better performance. We do tons of scraping, and moved off of scrapy + ghost (and trying several other options) for gevent + a streaming http parser written in C.

Comment: @TkTech, yes, but that's not what the poster is asking for. They simply want to be able to scrape data from dynamic pages, which can be achieved much more simply by using scrapy+splash than by completely re-inventing an already well established wheel by writing the entire thing from scratch using gevent and C....